# Presenting Tree Hierarchy with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have `terms` as below:

```
var terms = [
        { id: 1, name: "Name 1", parent: null },
        { id: 2, name: "Name 2", parent: 6 },
        { id: 3, name: "Name 3", parent: null },
        { id: 4, name: "Name 4", parent: 2},
        { id: 5, name: "Name 5", parent: 3 },
        { id: 6, name: "Name 6", parent: null },
        { id: 7, name: "Name 7", parent: 3 },
        { id: 8, name: "Name 8", parent: 9 },
        { id: 9, name: "Name 9", parent: 4 }
];
```

Now, I want to process `term` to have the output:

```
var orderedTerms = [
        { id: 1, name: "Name 1", parent: null , deep: 0},
        { id: 3, name: "Name 3", parent: null , deep: 0},
        { id: 5, name: "Name 5", parent: 3 , deep: 1},
        { id: 7, name: "Name 7", parent: 3 , deep: 1},
        { id: 6, name: "Name 6", parent: null , deep: 0},
        { id: 2, name: "Name 2", parent: 6, deep: 1},
        { id: 4, name: "Name 4", parent: 2, deep: 2},
        { id: 9, name: "Name 9", parent: 4, deep: 3},
        { id: 8, name: "Name 8", parent: 9, deep: 4 }
];
```

I think that someone can help me do it with Javascript (NodeJS). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Can you please share what you tried so far? It's easier to get a suggestion on what went wrong for you rather than someone providing the whole solution.

Comment: what is the sort criteria (id, parent or deep)?

Comment: I will try to do something and update my question later. However, if someone did it, they can help me beforehand

Comment: I would suggest to actually paste some code showing what you're trying to do..

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon while fetching the record from database if you sort by parentId asc, then it json string will be formed as expected right?

Comment: Tree hierarchy can be represented by node objects like this `{id:id,data:data,nodes:[node...],parent:parent,depth:depth}`. The tree is the root node.

Comment: I updated my question, I hope that I made it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little recursion will do.

```js
function getTree(parent, level) {
    level = level || 0;
    terms.forEach(function (a) {
        if (a.parent === parent) {
            orderedTerms.push({ id: a.id, name: a.name, parent: a.parent, deep: level });
            getTree(a.id, level + 1);
        }
    });
}

var terms = [
        { id: 1, name: "Name 1", parent: null },
        { id: 2, name: "Name 2", parent: 6 },
        { id: 3, name: "Name 3", parent: null },
        { id: 4, name: "Name 4", parent: 2 },
        { id: 5, name: "Name 5", parent: 3 },
        { id: 6, name: "Name 6", parent: null },
        { id: 7, name: "Name 7", parent: 3 },
        { id: 8, name: "Name 8", parent: 9 },
        { id: 9, name: "Name 9", parent: 4 }
    ],
    orderedTerms = [];

getTree(null);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(orderedTerms, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Bonus: Version with temporary storage.

```js
function sortTree(array) {

    function getTree(parent, level) {
        temp[parent] && temp[parent].forEach(function (a) {
            result.push({ id: array[a].id, name: array[a].name, parent: array[a].parent, deep: level });
            getTree(array[a].id, level + 1);
        });
    }

    var temp = {},
        result = [];

    array.forEach(function (a, i) {
        temp[a.parent] = temp[a.parent] || [];
        temp[a.parent].push(i);
    });
    getTree(null, 0);
    return result;
}

var terms = [
        { id: 1, name: "Name 1", parent: null },
        { id: 2, name: "Name 2", parent: 6 },
        { id: 3, name: "Name 3", parent: null },
        { id: 4, name: "Name 4", parent: 2 },
        { id: 5, name: "Name 5", parent: 3 },
        { id: 6, name: "Name 6", parent: null },
        { id: 7, name: "Name 7", parent: 3 },
        { id: 8, name: "Name 8", parent: 9 },
        { id: 9, name: "Name 9", parent: 4 }
    ];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortTree(terms), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not know why many people are not able to understand my question :)

Answer (score 2):

The code below should help you:

```js
var terms = [
  { id: 1, name: "Name 1", parent: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Name 2", parent: 6 },
  { id: 3, name: "Name 3", parent: null },
  { id: 4, name: "Name 4", parent: 2},
  { id: 5, name: "Name 5", parent: 3 },
  { id: 6, name: "Name 6", parent: null },
  { id: 7, name: "Name 7", parent: 3 },
  { id: 8, name: "Name 8", parent: 9 },
  { id: 9, name: "Name 9", parent: 4 }
];

var deep0 = terms.filter(function(term) {
  if (term.parent === null) {
    term.deep = 0;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

function makeTree(source, arr, final) {
  if (!final)
    final = arr.slice();
  
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    var deep = arr[0].deep + 1;
  
    source.forEach(function (item, i) {
      if (arr.map(function(term) {
        return term.id;
      }).indexOf(item.parent) >= 0) {
        item.deep = deep;
        var idx = final.map(function(term) {
          return (term.id === item.parent || term.parent === item.parent);
        }).lastIndexOf(true);
        final.splice(idx + 1, 0, item);
      }
    });
  
    makeTree(source, final.filter(function(term) {
      return term.deep === deep;
    }), final);
  }
  
  return final;
}

var final = makeTree(terms, deep0);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre><code>' + JSON.stringify(final, null, 2) + '</code></pre>';
```

The hole idea behind the code was to firstly find all the items which didn't have a parent, and then recursively iterate through their children (deeply), inserting them in the correct order into the final array.

If you have any doubts, leave a comment.

Comment: Thank for your understanding my question. Your code works for me.